# how to unbind click event for element which has "onclick=xxx"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to unbind a click event for an element which has `"onclick=xxx"`?

See my code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a" onclick="a()">a</button>
<button onclick="test()">test</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function a(){
        alert('a');
    }
    function test(){
        // how can I remove the click function for #a?
        // code bellow not works
        $('#a').unbind('click');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [jQuery's `prop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to remove the `onclick` attribute from the element:

```
$('#a').prop('onclick', null);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/6Na5z/1).

You shouldn't use removeAttr()` as stated in Milind Anantwar's answer as this will not work properly in old versions of IE:

> *Note: Removing an inline onclick event handler using `.removeAttr()` doesn't achieve the desired effect in Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.*
>
> Source: [jQuery's `removeAttr()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/).

Comment: how to do it in jquery 1.4.2?

Comment: @mingfish_004 You can do this using `attr()` instead: `$('#a').attr('onclick', null);`. You really shouldn't be using jQuery 1.4.2 though; this was released [almost 4 years ago](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/).

Answer (score 3):

You should be using:

```
$("#a").removeAttr("onclick");
```

or:

```
$("#a").prop("onclick", null);
```